# Computing the rotation angle that takes one given basis of $\Bbb R^2$ to another

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find an angle to rotate the basis
$$\left(\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right)$$
to the basis
$$\left(\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right),$$ but I am not sure as to how I must do this. How do I determine the angle? Is there some sort of rotation matrix that I must find?

Comment: Do you mean the bases of $\mathbb{R}^2$ formed by the column vectors of the two matrices?

Comment: Yes :) is the notation incorrect?

Comment: Strictly speaking a basis is an ordered set of vectors. Often it's useful to stick them together (to *adjoin* them, is the term of art) into a single matrix in order to manipulate them simultaneously, but we don't generally refer to the matrix we produce that way as a basis.

Comment: Oh alright :) thank you for letting me know :) so it is more a rotation of matrices that I am aiming for?

Comment: Looks like 45 degrees by inspection, just plot the basis vectors in the plane and think about it. Notice however that it will take more than a rotation to change from one basis into another since the first basis is a unit basis and the second is not.

Comment: Oh. So how must I go from the first basis to the second?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the (unique) matrix for the linear transformation that takes one basis to another. But if you call your matrices $B_1$ and $B_2$, resp., this amounts to finding a matrix $A$ such that $B_2 = A B_1$ (to see why this is, just ask separately what multiplication of each column of $B_1$ by $A$ means). In your case, $B_1 = I$, so $B_2 = A$.

Comment: Is the rotation angle not $\frac{3}{2}\pi$ cause of the old $x$ vector looks at $(-1,1)$ direction now.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand that. I have been told to find the angle of rotation is all...

Comment: Note that $\det A = -2$, so this transformation isn't a rotation at all. It turns out that it's a flip across a line together with a scaling. On the other hand, if we reversed the order of the vectors in either basis, it would be a rotation together with a scaling.

Comment: Oh ok I see it now. But then why was I asked to find some sort of angle?

Comment: I'm not sure, it depends on what the problem asked exactly. It /is/ meaningful to ask what the linear transformation $A$ does *separately* to each vector in the first bases, and for each vector it will be a rotation (together with a scaling).

Comment: Ah so I think that's probably what the question is after. How does that work?

Comment: It might help if you add the exact wording of the question to your problem

Comment: Oh my professor just gave me these and asked me to find an angle of rotation and then plot it on MatLab.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's what your professor has in mind, but the angle $\theta$ between two vectors $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$ satisfies $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = |\mathbf{a}||\mathbf{b}| \cos \theta$.

Comment: Let me try this :)

Comment: @Travis Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer As requested I've upgraded my comment to a detailed answer (giving two different methods in fact).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No rotation can map the first basis to the second: Rotations preserve length, but the first elements of the two bases have different lengths; specifically,
$$||(1, 0)^T|| = 1 \qquad \text{but} \qquad ||(1, -1)^T|| = \sqrt{2}.$$

Worse, the first basis is right-handed, but the second is left-handed, so they cannot be related by a rotation. For the purposes of saying something useful, we'll reverse the order of the second basis, which produces a right-handed basis. (This really is something substantial, as two bases with the same elements but in a different order are considered distinct: Bases are *ordered* tuples.)

It's not too hard to show, however, that two bases *are* related by an (oriented) similarity transformation, which is a composition of a rotation $R$ and a dilation $\Lambda$ (in either order).

If there is a similarity transformation that takes the first to the second, then the dilation factor must be the ratio of the lengths of the above vectors, namely $\sqrt{2}$ (so our dilation matrix is $\Lambda = \sqrt{2} I$), leaving only the angle of rotation to be determined. Using the usual cosine formula $${\bf a} \cdot {\bf b} = |{\bf a}| |{\bf b}| \cos \theta$$ to determine the (unoriented) angle between the vectors gives
\begin{align}
(1, 0)^T \cdot (1, 1)^T &= ||(1, 0)^T|| \, ||(-1, 1)^T|| \cos \theta\\
                      1 &= \sqrt{2} \cos \theta,
\end{align}
so (since $\theta \in [0, \pi]$),
$$\theta = \arccos \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

It remains to determine the direction of rotation (clockwise or anticlockwise). One can do this readily by visual inspection, but here's a quick way to check this algebraically: Computing the two dimensional cross product $\times: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \det \begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1\\a_2 & b_2\end{pmatrix} = a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1$$ gives that
$$(1, 0)^T \times (1, 1)^T = 1 > 0,$$
so the basis $((1, 0)^T, (1, 1)^T)$ is right-handed. Hence the rotation that takes the direction of the first to the direction of the other is anticlockwise, and thus the signed angle of rotation is
$$\color{#bf0000}{\frac{\pi}{4}}.$$

If we don't know a priori that the two bases are related by a similarity transform, then it remains to check exactly that the similarity transform we just produced takes the second vector in the first basis to the second in the second.

The rotation by a signed angle $\alpha$ has rotation matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\ \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha\end{pmatrix},$$
so the similarity matrix that takes $(1, 0)^T$ to $(1, 1)$ is
$$\Lambda R = (\sqrt{2} \Bbb I) \begin{pmatrix}\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) & -\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\ \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) & \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$
and multiplying shows that it relates the second vector in each basis as desired.

**Remark** A rather more advanced technique is somewhat faster: If we adjoin the vectors in the two bases to produce respective $2 \times 2$ matrices $A, B$, then the linear transformation that relates those bases is $P := BA^{-1}$ (if this isn't apparent, try checking this for yourself). Now, the matrix $P$ is a similarity transformation if $P^T P$ is some multiple of the identity matrix (in our case, $P^T P = 2 \Bbb I$, and we can read from this that the dilation factor must be $\sqrt{2}$). Now, the eigenvalues of $P$ are $1 \pm i$, and the argument of these values, $\pm \frac{\pi}{4}$, encodes the rotation angle; again, it's an easy matter to determine whether the rotation is clockwise or anticlockwise.